# how to publish the visual studio asp.net solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have converted my website into the solution, by creating new blank solution and adding existing website in it. Now i want to publish that solution, but it doesn't show me any option of publishing solution.

How can i publish the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you find the Publish option when you right click web app ?

Answer (score 2):

The publish command should be on the web site or web application project rather than on the solution itself.

[image]

Comment: This is one option. Normally it proposes to delete existing or to overwrite newer ones.

Comment: If you only want to replace specific files, you could always publish using the File System option, to another folder, and then only replace the specific files you want to in the live site.

Comment: @RohanBüchner- thanks for reply. i want to know can we publish the solution rather than publishing website?

Comment: @Rohan I don't really understand. Why would you want to publish the solution?? Normally your Web project should contain all the necessary resources to run properly. I.e. a web application contains all the compiled projects of your solution that are referenced from your Web Application project, in the `bin` folder, ready to be deployed. You always publish the "front-end" project which will then contain the references to potential subprojects.

Comment: @Rohan I still don't understand :) A Visual Studio Solution is just a construct for organizing different projects. In the end what counts is your "front-end" project, whether it is a Console Application, WinForms or WPF App or a Web Application. That's what you are going to release and therefore that's where the Publish option resides.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your project file and select publish website. keep in mind that if it asks to delete existing files then it is asking about already published files not the source files. So  it is safe to delete prior published files and publish new website, as well as you can change the folder for new published site

Answer (score 0):

You can get some help from the following article: [How to deploy ASP.Net Web Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/53075/How-to-deploy-ASP-NET-Web-Application-on-server)

But just a friendly recommendation that you do a bit of [researching yourself before asking questions](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/).